# fake Geolocation in chrome automation

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, gps, selenium-chromedriver

I need to automate geolocation in chrome using python script. I have to fake the latitude and longitude. I followed some links in stackoverflow but they gave errors.
               chromeDriver.executeScript("window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition=function(success){var position = {"coords" : {"latitude": "555","longitude": "999"}};success(position);}");

is there any other way i can change the location?

Answer (score 3):

Using Python with Selenium 3.141 and ChromeDriver 83.0

This is the working method I found:

```
params = {
  "latitude": 34.0207305,
  "longitude": -118.6919153,
  "accuracy": 100
}
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Emulation.clearGeolocationOverride", params)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape double quotes inside a string
please try with below code:

```
driver.execute_script("window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition=function(success){"+
                                    "var position = {\"coords\" : {\"latitude\": \"555\",\"longitude\": \"999\"}};"+
                                    "success(position);}");

print(driver.execute_script("var positionStr=\"\";"+
                                "window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos){positionStr=pos.coords.latitude+\":\"+pos.coords.longitude});"+
                                "return positionStr;"))
```

Answer (score 1):

It's actually now progammable by using the Chrome Devtools Protocol (cdp):

```
params = {
    "latitude": 50.1109,
    "longitude": 8.6821,
    "accuracy": 100
}

self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
self.driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.setGeolocationOverride", params)
self.driver.get('https://www.google.com/maps')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use execute_cdp but that is not found in `webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py` so you could do the following:

```
chrome_geolocation_format = {
            "location": {
                "latitude": 50.1109,
                "longitude": 8.6821
            }

driver.execute(Command.SET_LOCATION, chrome_geolocation_format)
```