# How to set a fake GeoLocation in Chrome for Selenium

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, geolocation

How to set a Fake GeoLocation in Chrome for Selenium? (Tried using locationcontext and also Javascript below but it doesnt seem to work)

I have tried the solution here - [fake Geolocation in chrome automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31755633/fake-geolocation-in-chrome-automation) but it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Chrome Devtools Protocol (cdp):

```
params = {
    "latitude": 50.1109,
    "longitude": 8.6821,
    "accuracy": 100
}

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.setGeolocationOverride", params)
driver.get('https://www.google.com/maps')
```