# C# chrome selenium fake geolocation

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I'm writing automation for chrome selenium. After the browser is opened, I have to change location. [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43198026/how-to-set-a-fake-geolocation-in-chrome-for-selenium?newreg=f930d8d36c1a4f8988c17ca73117dd1e) how can I make the structure in the link for c #?

Comment: The codes are written for java. I don't know how I can do this in C #.

Comment: Huh? What's Java?

Comment: methings python. I dont know

Comment: Have you read through the link above yet?

Comment: Sorry. I accidentally opened another link. I'm reviewing, thanks.