# Selenium Tests-Verify login

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have a web application which starts with user login page. I need to test this login process. If  the user is in his home country then he is directed to his user page. But, if he logs in from a different country he is shown an authentication page before directing him to his user page. The authentication page has some security questions that need to be answered. I have used a chrome extension(Geo Proxy) and sikuli to change the proxy address. But, the page takes too much time to load and hence, my test fails.

Comment: [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: When you edit your question to add more details and code, make sure you add a tag for the programming language you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is possible to spoof your geolocation for the ChromeDriver. You may be able to try this approach..

ChromeOptions are essentially settings that you pass to your ChromeDriver, may be possible to do here as well. Here is an answer for this using python, I am sure you can find examples for whatever language you are coding in. Just do some research around geolocation and ChromeDriver/ChromeOptions.

[fake Geolocation in chrome automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31755633/fake-geolocation-in-chrome-automation)